# Странное поведение location

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер

Конфигурация сервера:

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    root /home/Web/www/$server_name/;
    index index.php index.html;

    charset utf-8;

    location ~* \.php$
    {
        return 403;
    }

    location /
    {
    }
}
```

Индексный файл - index.php. При загрузке `example.com/` Nginx отдает именно его (т.к. указано `index index.php index.html;`), срабатывает `location ~* \.php$` и выдает 403 ошибку, все ОК, как и должно.

Но если я внесу такое изменение в блок:

```
location /
{
    proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```

То при загрузке `example.com/` будет сразу проксировать на Backend, хотя index стоит, и обрабатываемый его location тоже.

Я не понимаю, почему если блок `location /` пустой, то будет обрабатываться подходящий `location ~* \.php$`, если же поставить проксирование, то запрос начинает обрабатывать `location /`.

Почему так? Не срабатывает настройка `index index.php index.html;` или что? Как это починить?

Comment: Потому что location/ больше не пытается ничего искать на диске. Что и зачем вы хотите починить?

Comment: Пока ваш вопрос выглядит как [Ошибка XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy). Зачем вам нужен `index.php` если вы всё равно проксируете запрос?

Comment: @AlexeyTen чтобы при переходе к example.com/ обрабатывало `location ~* \.php$ {}`, при переходе к example/test.html и подобное, проксировало запрос. `return 403;`  приведен просто в качестве примера.

Comment: Что «и подобное»? А, например, `example.com/about/` куда должен вести?

Comment: @AlexeyTen **example.com/about/** тоже должен обрабатываться `location ~* \.php$ {}`, если в папке about есть файл index.php (как указано в директории `index index.php index.html;`). Я так понял, что директива `index` должна делать внутренний редирект на **index.php** или **index.html**, но она этого НЕ делает, если в блоке `location /{}` стоит строка `proxy_pass http://backend;`.
 -
_«и подобное»_, т.е. все файлы, кроме .php.
Мне надо сделать так: если файл расширения **.php**, значит просто делаем, к примеру, `return 403;`, если другие - проксируем запрос.

Comment: Если ввести **example.com/index.php**, то `location ~* \.php$ {}` срабатывает, в независимости, есть ли что-то в блоке `location /{}` или нет.

Comment: почему так не знаю, очевидно, что index обрабатывается после location. хотя скорее всего location обрабатывается несколько раз, сначала до index, потом, если идет обращение к локальной ФС, и нет файла, обрабатывается index, а потом еще раз location уже для нового пути. И видимо надо делать проксирование с более сложным условием, что бы под него просто не подпадали те url, которые должны быть обработаны локально. например `location ~* /.$ { proxy ... }` хотя за точность не ручаюсь, воспринимает ли `$`, уместно ли именно `~*` ...

Answer (score 1):

Вообще [ваш пример разобран в документации на nginx](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/request_processing.html):

> Обработка запроса “/” более сложная. Ему соответствует только
>   префиксный location “/”, поэтому запрос обрабатывается в нём. **Затем**
>   директива index проверяет существование индексных файлов согласно
>   своих параметров

Кроме этого, весьма рекомендую многократно, до полного просветления перечитывать раздел "порядок применения location" (например [раз](http://dragonflybsd.blogspot.ru/2012/12/nginx-location.html) и [два](http://docs.mirocow.com/doku.php?id=nginx:location)).

Конкретно ваш пример разобранный до самой мелочи.

Как разбирается URI `/` в вашем конфиге:

А) для случая пустого `location /`:

1. Для запроса `/` подходит только один location -- `location /`. 
   Этот location пустой, но наследует root и index от блока server.
2. Применяется внутреннее перенаправление (директива index) c `/` на `/index.php`. Начинается обработка НОВОГО запроса.
3. Для запроса `/index.php` подходят как `location ~* \.php$`, так и `location \`, будет использоваться (см. порядок приоритетов location) location заданный регуляркой, он отдаст 403 и закончит обработку запроса.

Для наглядности эквивалентный конфиг сервера:

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    root /home/Web/www/$server_name/;

    charset utf-8;

    location ~* \.php$
    {
        return 403;
    }

    location /
    {
        index index.php index.html;
    }
}
```

Так наглядно видно, что ваш пример полностью соответствует разобранному в документации.

Б) для случая location с прокси-сервером

1. Для запроса `/` подходит только один location -- `location /`. 
   Этот location передаёт обработку бекенду, на этом обработка запроса nginx'ом закончена.

Это что касается запроса, заданного в самом вопросе. В комментариях был ещё один запрос:

> Если ввести example.com/index.php, то location ~* .php$ {}
>   срабатывает, в независимости, есть ли что-то в блоке location /{} или
>   нет.

Для запроса `/index.php` подходит какой location? Правильно -- оба, но первым будет применяться location ~* .php$ (см. приоритет location), а в нём у вас обработка заканчивается выдачей 403.

> Как это починить?

Выше я описывал то, как работает ваш конфиг. С вашей точки зрения он работает "неправильно". А вот как правильно -- вы не пишете, поэтому тут нужно, чтобы вы чётко поставили задачу -- что вы, собственно, хотите от nginx? Я полностью согласен с тем комментарием `Что «и подобное»?` -- это неконкретно и непонятно.

Подозреваю, что вам нужно `location = / {...}` но не уверен. Возможно, стоит задать новый вопрос, в котором сослаться на текущий и чётко пояснить, какие вы хотите видеть location и что куда хотите отправлять. И лучше не пытайтесь "для примера" заменять одно действие другим: хотите отдать файл -- так и пишите, а не "отдать файл, но вместо этого для примера  403". Это только запутывает и вас как спрашивающего и отвечающих.